# sdk manager failed to create sdcard in the avd folder AND unable to find userdata.img

Tags: android, eclipse, emulation, sd-card

I'm at my wits end now. I've been getting either one of these errors trying to set up an android emulator on Eclipse. I'm running Ubuntu.

I've read ALL of the answers that I've found for this error but nothing it working for me. Please help!!!

I have uninstalled and installed the android SDK tools several times, including the system image. I've tried to update ia32-libs although I get the following error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ia32-libs : Depends: ia32-libs-multiarch but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages
```

After trying

```
sudo dpkg -r --force-all librtmp0
sudo apt-get install librtmp0
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

I still get the same error as above.